# jquery selecting a particular class from an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to group related elements using class name. They, in turn, are all related as they are all using the same prefix for the class name. Example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="category-fruit"></li>
  <li class="category-grain"></li>
  <li class="category-meat"></li>
  <li class="category-fruit"></li>
  <li class="category-meat"></li>
</ul>
```

Visually, I want a hover function on each that, when hovered, will apply the same visual effect to the other elements sharing the same class name.

While it's easy to select a particular LI with a particular class, how would I go about picking a particular class from the hovered LI?

So in pseudo code

```
$("li").hover(function(){
    $(this).[get-the-class-beggining-with"category"]
})
```

I'm guessing this involves using the starts with selector ([attribute^=value])

Comment: To clarify your question. Are you saying that if `category-meat` is hovered, all other `li's` with `category-meat` should be selected as well? The same would go for `category-fruit`. If it were hovered, you want to show both it (the first li) and the other fruit one (the fourth li) as hovered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @CMS's awesome lead, I have posted a [working example](http://jsbin.com/icepo3) of this solution to JSBin.

I have come up with a solution that allows you to have additional classes on the `li's` and, after it finds the correct siblings it caches it for future use to speed up the execution:

```
$(function(){
    $("li").hover(function(){
        var $this    = $(this),
            $cache   = $this.data('hoverCache');

        if(!$cache){
            var category = this.className.match(/category\-.+?\b/)      
            $this.data('hoverCache', $this.siblings('.' + category).andSelf().addClass('hover') );
        } else {
            $cache.addClass('hover');
        }

    }, function(){
        var $cache = $(this).data('hoverCache');
        if($cache) $cache.removeClass('hover');
    });
})
```

So it doesn't get lost in this optimized example, here is the relevant code to your question:

```
var category = this.className.match(/category\-.+?\b/);
$(this).siblings('.' + category).andSelf();
```

This finds the category from the `className` (there can be additional classes) and then it finds other children of the same parent using `.siblings` and then includes itself so you can add the `hover` class to the elements at one time.

I tested this code using Firefox and your provided HTML and it worked great. Let me know if its not what you needed!

Comment: thanks. I'll have to study this for a bit but looks interesting!

Comment: @DA I updated my answer so you can just skip to the relevant parts relating to your question. Let me know if that is clearer.

Comment: @dcneiner ah! yes, that does clarify things. Clever! Thanks!

Comment: @dcneiner I noticed you use both 'this' and '$(this)'. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: **@dcneiner:** +1, nice example, JSBin is a great resource!, **@DA:** with `this` you access the raw DOM element, with `$(this)` you can use jQuery specific methods on that element.

Comment: Thanks @CMS! Great clarification of `this` and `$(this)`. Also, I normally store the result of `$(this)` in a variable if I plan on using it more than once and I can't chain it. In those cases you will see `$this` in my code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [attributeStartsWith](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith) selector:

```
$("li[class^=category]").hover(/*...*/);
```

Check an example with your markup [here](http://jsbin.com/elipe3).

**Edit:** To get the class name you can use `this.className` or, use the [`attr`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) function, for example:

```
$("li[class^=category]").each(function(){
  var className = $(this).attr('className');  
  // this.className, or attr('class'), which will be mapped to className
});
```

And by the way, you can also use the [`filter(fn)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter) method to select the `li` elements which their className starts with 'category':

```
$("li").filter(function () {
  return /category-.+/.test(this.className);
}).hover(/*...*/);
```

Comment: that will select the dom object with that class, but what if I want to grab the entire class name itself?

Comment: Inside the `hover` function, `this.className` will be the fastest way of getting all the classes applied to the current `li`. If there is only one, then great. If not, filtering still has to be applied.

Comment: Just noticed your JSBin link... very cool! I really need to start using that!